# C/C++ thread calling filling up memory

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to make a server(multithreading) and I run into a problem: it is filling up memory. So I decided to do a simple test. Here is the code in main:

```
int main(void)
{

int x;
while(1)
{
    cin>>x;

    uintptr_t thread = 0;

    //handle(NULL);
    thread = _beginthread(handle, 0, NULL);

    if (thread == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't create thread: %d\n", GetLastError());
    }
}
}
```

And here is the 'handle' function:

```
void handle(void *)
{
    ;
}
```

I open task manager, and I am looking there to see how much RAM my process takes.
If the function main is as you see right now, after each press of key 1 and then press enter(so the thing inside the while will execute), the RAM that the process takes increases with 4k(basically, each time the thread is created or something like that, it will leak 4k of memory). If I do this multiple times, it will keep increasing, each time with 4k.

If in the function main I comment this 'thread = _beginthread(handle, 0, 0);' and uncomment this '//handle(NULL);', then the process will not increase it's RAM memory.

Anyone have any ideas how to free that 4k of memory?

I am compiling it with codeblocks, but same result is compiling it with visual studio.

EDIT: from MSDN: "When the thread returns from that routine, it is terminated automatically."
Also I put '_endthread();' in my handle function, but the result IS THE SAME!

Comment: Don't you need to close the thread handle using CloseHandle?

Comment: You are aware that there's not **one** thread but very many of them?

Comment: In task manager it shows that there is only 1 thread.

Comment: 1 process != 1 thread. In Task Manager, go to View -> Select Columns -> Check "Threads" and you should be able to see your thread count increasing.

Comment: I have that Threads collumn and it's showing 1 everytime. It's not increasing.

Comment: @CoertMetz: no, if you use _beginthread you must not close the thread handle yourself.  The _endthread routine closes it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Each time around the loop this program creates a new thread. The program never closes any threads.

I think what you have demonstrated is that the memory cost of creating a thread is around 4K.

Presuming you don't want an ever-increasing number of threads, either you should close one before creating another or at least give up when you've got enough.

---

On further reflection, the above is wrong. I tried your program, and it will not and cannot do what you say, unless there is some important part of the story you've left out.

1. The line with "cin" just blocks. I pressed enter a few times, but nothing interesting happened. So I took it out.
2. This program does not leak. Each thread terminates when the `handle` function finishes.

Here is the code I wrote, adapting yours.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <process.h>

using namespace std;

int nthread = 0;

void handle(void *) {
  nthread++;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  while(nthread < 50000) {
    cout << nthread << ' ';
    uintptr_t thread = 0;
    thread = _beginthread(handle, 0, NULL);
    if (thread == -1) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't create thread: %d\n", GetLastError());
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

It runs 50,000 iterations and uses a grand total of less than 1MB of memory. Exactly as expected.

Something doesn't add up.

Comment: And how can I close the thread at the end of the function 'handle'?

Comment: I did...still filling up the memory.

Comment: You have an answer to you original question. If you have changed your program you need to ask a new question. We do question and answer, not interactive debugging. Sorry.

Comment: Threads exit automatically when the thread function returns, so adding _endthread() should make no difference.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Of course, you're absolutely right. So I rewrote my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Every thread need some memory for it's own infrastructure, that's what the 4K is. When the thread terminates (this depends on your implementation), this 4K will be freed. You should use API functions for joining the the child threads, therefore you should keep the handle(s). Calling the handle function directly is just a function call, no memory is allocated in this case.

EDIT:

Your "handle" function terminates immediately. As far as I know (at least for posix/linux) there are options at creation time for auto-free the memory, or otherwise joining is required. The one thread you see is the "main" thread of the process itself. This way your programm is producing memory leaks.

Comment: Windows doesn't work that way.  There’s no “join” or “detach”.  Instead, if you want to wait for a thread to exit, you wait on its handle, then close the handle.  And if you want to do the equivalent of a detach, you either just close the handle straight away, or you could have the thread close its own handle (which is what happens if you call the C runtime’s `_endthread()`, but *not* `_endthreadex()`).